# Laravel 5 database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

When I try to connect my Laravel project to Mysql database like;

```
APP_ENV=production
DB_HOST=160.153.16.56:3306
DB_USERNAME=ozanozanozan
DB_DATABASE=software_db
DB_PASSWORD=ozanvolkan1
```

and I run *php Artisan migrate*,

I see an alert like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database permissions. First make sure that the user 'ozanozanozan'@'88.246.41.148' exists in database,

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'ozanozanozan'; 
// This will show all of the hosts that user can connect from
```

and make sure that the user has access to the software_db database.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ozanozanozan'@'88.246.41.148';
```

Comment: #1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_oz8Vr6mtGH'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'  error for those 2 queries by the way i can connect using localhost:8889 using MAMP with no problem user:root pass:root and for the user ozanozanozan all privillages are already given

Comment: You need to log into your database as root or as a user with full privileges to make sure that the user exists and has access to the database.  If the webpage at localhost:8889 doesn't access the database at all or uses different credentials, it won't help diagnose your laravel issue.

Comment: in localhost the root user or a user that i create with full privileges has an extra parameter named host. If you set this host to localhost initially it works  but if you make it any host it still doesn't work. I cannot set this thing on my hosting panel or any other interface. And also sql queries for create user doesn't work.

Comment: If it works with localhost but not another host, then the permissions for the database user are wrong. You'll have to either use localhost or correct the database user's permissions.

Comment: this setting is made while creating the user not in permissions